# Mushroom Identificaton(USA)

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I need help identifying a perculiar species of mushroom found in my yard today. Color is orange-yellow, around 3-4 inches total radius, its a cluster of tiny to medium mushrooms. They were found near an oak tree. Location is southern Georgia, USa.

[image: side view]
[image: top view]
[image: underneath]
[image: top angle]
[image: underneath 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These could be specimens of *Omphalotus Illudens* based on the orange/yellow color, the time of the year, their association with decaying wood (an oak in this case) and your location (eastern North America)

You can read more about these species in this reference: [Messiah College](https://www.messiah.edu/Oakes/fungi_on_wood/gilled%20fungi/species%20pages/Omphalotus%20illudens.htm)

Comment: I did some research on Omphalotus Illudens (Jack-o-lanterns) and found that they were bioluminescent. The mushrooms i found are not. Is there a possibility that there is a subspecies of Illundens that are not bioluminescent?

Comment: You are right about the claimed bioluminescent properties, however this phenomena is not always happening. Apparently some people that study these mushrooms sometimes have to wait hours in the dark to be able to see the glowing and some even say the bioluminescent claims are completely false ( like this reference: [mushroom expert](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/omphalotus_illudens.html) ). I unfortunately lack the expertise to say for sure if they are bioluminescent or not.

Comment: MikeKatz45, I had cut down a tree about a month ah go, about a foot away from the clusters location. I noticed that the post said "Occurrence on wood substrate: or on the ground from decaying underground roots; ". This somewhat fits in with this type since of the location and the surroundings. Could it be possible that it might actually be it?